# Find longest substring in a string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I'd like to know how to do this:

```
string1= "cggt"
string2="ccgg"
```

The max substring `string1` contains `string2` is only one "c" (`string1` must have continue `string2` segments like if `string1` is "ccgt", then return should be maxsubstring "cc").

More example:

```
string1:"EggAndApple"  
string2:"AppleEggAnd"
```

I want to find max substring in `string1` contains `string2` should be"Apple" (Must started with beginning of `string2`)

But my code below will give "EggAnd" as result

I searched some solution to return the result maxsubstring is "cgg".
The code is

```
int findOverlap( std::string str1,  std::string str2)
    {
     if(str1.empty() || str2.empty())
     {
          return 0;
     }

     int *curr = new int [str1.size()];
     int *prev = new int [str1.size()];
     int *swap = nullptr;
     int maxSubstr = 0;

     for(int i = 0; i<str2.size(); ++i)
     {
          for(int j = 0; j<str1.size(); ++j)
          {
               if(str1[j] != str2[i])
               {
                    curr[j] = 0;

               }
               else
               {
                    if(i == 0 )
                    {
                         curr[j] = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         curr[j] = 1 + prev[j-1];
                    }

                    if(maxSubstr < curr[j])
                    {
                         maxSubstr = curr[j];
                    }
               }
          }
          swap=curr;
          curr=prev;
          prev=swap;
     }
     delete [] curr;
     delete [] prev;
     return maxSubstr;
}
```

How to modify this code to meet my requirements or how to write new segment of code to solve my problem?

Comment: What class is this for?

Comment: For "cggt" & "ccgg" the max substring is 3, not 1 ('cgg' is contained in both strings). I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve, could you please provide some other examples for substrings?

Comment: Yes, "cgg" is contained in both strings, I have edited the question. What I want is to find longest continued string segment of string 2 in string 1. like string 1"eggandapple" string2 "appleeggand", my expected return should be"apple" but my code posted will find "eggand". the returned string must started with the begin of string2 .

Comment: Your description is very confusing. Do you want to find the first occurrence of string intersection, or you want to find the longest intersection? According to your comment above you seem like looking for the first occurrence as your say `must start with the beginning of string2`

Answer (score 1):

Below is my modification for your question, I did not compile and run, but it should work.

```
char* str1 = "EggAndApple";
char* str2 = "AppleEggAnd";

int* maxSubStrLen = new int [strlen(str1)];
memset(maxSubStrLen, 0, sizeof(int) * strlen(str1));

// start index of max substring
int  maxGlobalSubStrIdx = -1;
// length of max substring
int  maxGlobalSubStrLen = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str2); ++i)
{
    for(int j = i; j < strlen(str1); ++j)
    {
        if(str1[j] != str2[i])
        {
            continue;
        }

        // str1[j] == str2[i]
        {
            // find substring started from (j - i) ?
            if(maxSubStrLen[j - i] == i) {
                maxSubStrLen[j - i]++;
                if(maxGlobalSubStrLen < maxSubStrLen[j - i])
                {
                    maxGlobalSubStrLen = maxSubStrLen[j - i];
                    maxGlobalSubStrIdx = j - i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
delete [] maxSubStrLen;
printf("maxGlobalSubStrLen:%d, maxGlobalSubStrIdx:%d\n", maxGlobalSubStrLen, maxGlobalSubStrIdx);
```

Comment: I tested it in VS2012, It does not work. the string maxSubStrLen[j - i] are not initiated, so maxSubStrLen[j - i] == i may never be true.

Comment: slightly update above source code: a. memset to init whole array as zero; b. boundary check to make sure (j - i) is not negative. Please check my update source code, which output correct result: "maxGlobalSubStrLen:5, maxGlobalSubStrIdx:6"